# Migrating .net core 2.2 to .net standard 2.0 causes warnings

Tags: asp.net-core-2.2, .net-standard-2.0

I am migrating .net core 2.2 project to .net standard 2.0 lib project by
editing the csproj file  tag value. Everything seems to go smoothly
and work well when running the code, but build gives warnings:

Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2081, 5): [MSB3277] Found conflicts between different versions of "System.Collections" that could not be resolved.  These reference conflicts are listed in the build log when log verbosity is set to detailed.
Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2081, 5): [MSB3277] Found conflicts between different versions of "System.Console" that could not be resolved.  These reference conflicts are listed in the build log when log verbosity is set to detailed.

Totally it is 9 conflicts, above only two of them

Can it be referenced lib (.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1.4) that is causing this?

I´ve tried also create new project with same dependencies, but no luck with that.

Comment: "Can it be referenced lib (.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1.4) that is causing this?" - seeming as you cannot reference .NET Core 3.1 projects from a .NET Standard 2.0 project, that should be immediately obvious to you.

Comment: A core 2.2-3.1 can defiantly reference a standard 2.0  but a standard 2.0 or 2.1 can not reference a core x. If that is what u are trying to do its not possible. if not then give more details about which project reference which.

Comment: Thanks for answers, I think I got it now